# WPF Datagrid not recieving incrementing values

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid in MainWindow.xaml which data is being passed to from another form (AddFixtures.xaml). I have a class of 'Fixture' in AddFixtures.xaml.cs:

```
public class Fixture
    {
        public int fixtureID { get; set; }
        public int channelID { get; set; }
        public string fixtureName { get; set; }
        public string position { get; set; }
        public string patch { get; set; }
        public string mode { get; set; }
        public string power { get; set; }
        public string direction { get; set; }
        public int channelsUsed { get; set; }
    }
```

Which is received by this (MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
fixtureData.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(
            delegate (object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    FixtureView.Items.Add(fixtureData);
                }
            }
        );
```

Basically, I enter information into another form and press a button, the data is then added to the DataGrid. I have some information that needs to increment based on a quantity. I have got this to increment but in the DataGrid, it always shows the first value entered. Code below is executed when I click the button in (AddFixtures.xaml.cs):

```
private void BtnAddFixture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int quantity = Int32.Parse(txtQuantity.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            MainWindow.fixtureData.Add(new Fixture()
            {
                fixtureID = Int32.Parse(txtFixtureID.Text),
                channelID = Int32.Parse(txtChannelID.Text),
                fixtureName = cbxFixture.Text,
                position = cbxPosition.Text,
                patch = cbxUniverse.Text + "." + txtChannel.Text,
                mode = cbxMode.Text,
                power = cbxSocca.Text + "." + cbxWay.Text,
                direction = "Forwards",
                channelsUsed = Int32.Parse(lblChannels.Content.ToString())
            });
            fixtureID++;
            channelID++;
            txtFixtureID.Text = fixtureID.ToString();
            txtChannel.Text = channelID.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: As a very first step, you should create a view model class with a FixtureData property like this: `public ObservableCollection<Fixture> FixtureData { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Fixture>();`. Then both windows would assign the same instance of the view model class to their `DataContext` property. The DataGrid would then have its ItemsSource bound like `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FixtureData}" .../>`, while the Button would add items to the collection like `var vm = (MainViewModel)DataContext; vm.FixtureData.Add(new Fixture { ... });`. Search the web for `MVVM`.

Comment: This makes sense but how would I go about assigning the same instance of the vm class to the data context?

Comment: Create one MainViewModel object and assign that to the DataContext of as many windows as necessary. E.g. create it in the MainWindow constructor like `DataContext = new MainViewModel();`. If you open another window from the MainWindow, write `var newWindow = new ChildWindow { DataContext = DataContext };`

Comment: Besides that, the line `FixtureView.Items.Add(fixtureData);` looks dubious. Seems like you are adding the whole `fixtureData` collection as a single item. Certainly not correct.

Answer (score -1):

if you debug the  *FixtureView.Items* are the added items avaible in the list ? If so, you have a problem, that the view does not get recognised when a item is added ? 
Maybe you change the source of the grid to a [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)  --> this will update the view if anything is updated!

Comment: While this should generally better be a comment than an answer, it is also partly wrong. Even with using an ObservableCollection the UI will not be update when an item property changes. Not at all "*if anything is updated*".